# How to substitute an Integer by a sum in an expression

Tags: python, sympy

Hi I edited my question because I found out that my problem was larger: I can't use the subs function:
This:

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")

expr = x
expr.subs(x, y)
print(expr)
```

Gives me an "x".
May this be because I'm using sympy with anaconda?

**Question previous to the editing:**

*I'm new at sympy, here's my problem:
I would like to replace the value 5 by a sum (3+2) and can't manage it with a .subs, i tried it this way:*

```
from sympy import *
    
def change(expr):
    '''
    if it's a leaf substitute 5 by 3+2
    '''
    if len(expr.args)==1:
        expr.subs(UnevaluatedExpr(5), UnevaluatedExpr(3) + UnevaluatedExpr(2))
        print(expr)
    for arg in expr.args: 
        change(arg)
    
expr = UnevaluatedExpr(5)*UnevaluatedExpr(10)-UnevaluatedExpr(5)**UnevaluatedExpr(2)
#i.e. 5*10-5^2
change(expr)          #should substitue 5s by (2+3)
```

*But instead it does not change anything :/
If you have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong I would be very please, thanks in advance !
Edit: I had an error in the subs function but it still doesn't work now it's fixed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since expressions are immutable, using `subs` on an expression does nothing to the original expression, it only creates a new (possibly different) expression. So the observation that `expr` is still `x` after your did `expr.subs(x,y)` is consistent with that. If you had printed `expr.subs(x,y)` you would have seen `y`.

Also, since your `change` function does not return the new expression when you check the value of `expr` it is unchanged.

If you want to write your own function you can ask for help on that. If you want to replace an Integer with a sum you can use the `subs` method itself:

```py
>>> expr = UnevaluatedExpr(5)*UnevaluatedExpr(10)-UnevaluatedExpr(5)**UnevaluatedExpr(2)
>>> expr.subs(5, UnevaluatedExpr(2)+3)
(3 + 2)*10 - (3 + 2)**2
>>> expr  # unchanged unless you do expr = expr.subs(5, UnevaluatedExpr(2)+3)
5*10 - 5**2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the arguments of `subs` in the wrong order. Here is how you do that:

```
expr.subs(UnevaluatedExpr(5), UnevaluatedExpr(3) + UnevaluatedExpr(2))
# out: (2 + 3)*10 - (2 + 3)**2
```

Comment: Oh thank's it's true i'll edit but it still doesn't work for me :/